# Check Model for true values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I have a model of mostly boolean properties with 5 additonal strings and an int.  My question is there a way to check if there are at least 3 true values on this model.  I know I can just loop through the values but my property names are currently different names instead of of checkbox1 checkbox2 and so on.  I would like to keep the names unique if possible.  I'm not sure if what I want is even possible.

Model:

```
namespace FacilitesPledgeForm.Models {
    public class FacilitiesPledge 
    {
     public bool LightsOff {get; set;}
     public bool PowerDown {get; set;}
     public bool PrintLess {get; set;}
     public bool Stairs {get; set;}
     public string test1 {get; set;}
     public string test1 {get; set;}
     public string test2 {get; set;}
     public string test3 {get; set;}
     public string test4 {get; set;}
     public string test5 {get; set;}
     public int num {get; set;}
   }

}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Submit_PledgeForm(FacilitiesPledge facilitiesPledge)
    {
        //I want to loop here for at least 3 true values and if there isn't add an error to the model to make it invalid

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Index", facilitiesPledge);
        }

        facilitiesPledge.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
        facilitiesPledge.Email = User.Identity.Name.ToUpper();
        facilitiesPledge.Year = DateTime.Now.Year;

        new PledgeFormStore().InsertPledgeAcceptance(facilitiesPledge);

        return View("SuccessfulSubmission");
    }
```

Comment: where is your relevant code?

Comment: I added sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your Boolean members to list

using linq check if count of true Boolean member more than or equeal to 3 reteurn true

```
public class FacilitiesPledge
{
    public bool LightsOff { get; set; }
    public bool PowerDown { get; set; }
    public bool PrintLess { get; set; }
    public bool Stairs { get; set; }
    public string test1 { get; set; }
    public string test2 { get; set; }
    public string test3 { get; set; }
    public string test4 { get; set; }
    public string test5 { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        //add your boolean members
        List<bool> items = new List<bool> { LightsOff, PowerDown, PrintLess, Stairs };
        //if count of true Boolean member more than or equeal to 3 reteurn true 
        bool isValid = items.Count(x => x == true) >= 3;
        return isValid;
    }
}
```